# ArrayList not always adding object on first try

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list that is supposed to add an object to it, however the first time I try to add an object to the ArrayList the object is not added.

Main Class:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    char letter =  e.getKeyChar();
    if(player!=null){
        if(letter==' ') {
           player.dropBomb(bomb);
        }
     }
}
```

Player Class:

```
    private int x,y;
    private int score;
    private Rectangle rect;
    private Color color;
    private Upgrade upgrades;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private int bombCount, bombMax;
    private int bombs;
    private ArrayList<Bomb> bombList;
    private ArrayList<Explosion> explodeList;
    private int power;
    private boolean dead;
    private int lives;



    public Player(int X, int Y,BufferedImage img) {
        x=X;
        y=Y;
        rect=new Rectangle(x+4,y+3,32-4-5,29-3-4);
        bombCount=0;
        bombMax=6;
        bombList=new ArrayList<Bomb>();
        explodeList=new ArrayList<Explosion>();
        power=1;
        image=img;
        dead=false;
        lives=3;
    }

public void dropBomb(BufferedImage bomb){
        out.println("DROPPING "+bombCount);//bombCount is initialized as 0; bombMax is intialized as 6
        if(bombCount<bombMax){
            bombCount++;
            out.println(bombCount+ " "+bombList.size());//bombList is an Arraylist<Bomb>
            bombList.add(new Bomb(x+16,y+16));
            out.println(bombList);
        }
        out.println("DROPPINGTest "+bombCount);
}
```

There is only one player.

Bomb Class constructor:

```
private int power;
private int timeLeft;
private int x,y;
private Rectangle rect;
private boolean canWalk;

public Bomb(int X,int Y){
        x=X;
        y=Y;
        rect=new Rectangle(x,y,32,32);
        timeLeft=200;
        power=4;
        canWalk=true;
  }
```

first time dropBomb is called:

```
DROPPING0
1 0
[]
DROPPINGTest 1
```

Second Time dropBomb is called:

```
DROPPING1
2 0
[Bomb@e1456c]
DROPPINGTest 2
```

The only thread that I am running is in the main class.
I am using threads in the main class, I have tried lowering and raising the sleep time on the thread and the result did not change. Any clue on the reason this is happening? Also there is a significant delay the first time that dropBomb is pressed between line 2 and 3 of the output.

You can view all of my code at: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7qyWqb6iazxfklTcmVBUEcxQThJNzlPNzRBcnM4Vkx1T0N1WEVfcnFUenlqOUxaWUF2V28&usp=sharing

Comment: Where is the bombList constructed? Maybe it's happening multiple times in different threads?

Comment: Please show us what type is `bombList`?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I assume 'ArrayList'

Comment: a) I assume the problem is in some code which you have not posted. b) the key to multithreading is correct synchronization. Read about the `synchronized` keyword

Comment: I have updated my post to include more info.

Comment: @Ian. what above users asking is we need to know where you create bombList  that is List<Bomb> = new ArrayList<Bomb>() -- where is that call ? does this get called for each thread ?  you need to find-- any situation where this list can be reset unexpectedly?

Comment: What is `bombCount`?  Is it a static member or an instance member?  What about `bombList`?  How many `Player` instances are there?  You tagged this question with "multithreading", but what other threads are running besides the EDT?  What are those threads doing?  I think you need to show some more code.

Comment: @jameslarge I added some extra code and I am only using one thread in the main class also you can view all of my code in the google drive that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case a problem may be in concurrent access to list. Method 'keyPressed' may be called by different threads, so 'dropBomb' also will be called by different threads.
If the problem is it, you should synchronize 'dropBomb' or use some thread-safety list implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. I fixed it by adding to bombList when Player is constructed and then remove the new Bomb right after it.

```
public Player(int X, int Y,BufferedImage img) {
        bombList=new ArrayList<Bomb>();
        explodeList=new ArrayList<Explosion>();
        bombList.add(new Bomb());         //added this line
        bombList.remove(0);               //added this line
    }
```

For some reason unknown to me adding to the arrayList bombList for the first time would result in a significant delay resulting in bombList being cleared by another method.